# Clarification about rejected Flags

Tags: discussion, off-topic, flagging

I have flag [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59949/packet-tracer-icons-too-small) Question for off topic But It was rejected. But it looks like a off topic because question does not contain any thing about Network engineering.

I flagged because of this point "

> NE is a site for to ask and provide answers about professionally
>   managed networks in a business environment. Your question falls
>   outside the areas our community decided are on topic. Please visit the
>   help center for more details. If you disagree with this closure,
>   please ask on Network Engineering Meta.

But Someone can argue about this point in help center under on topic.

> tools used by network professionals

I understand mentioned point in this way. 
"Packet Tracer is not professional simulator, Although it is professional question looks like a appearance of the packet tracer, It is not involving anything about NE. It could be resolution changes in his computer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't the one handling the flags, but no moderator should be needed to label a question off topic. That should be voted on by the community.

I do agree however that you can question if this question belongs on this site. You quoted the appropriate points from the help center, and my *personal* opinion would be that this question does not really belong here. However, I decided not to vote, since my vote to close would automatically be decisive.

Comment: I agree that the question doesn't really belong on NE. I closed the flag because there were no close votes, and it did relate to the on-topic lab reason. It is likely to never get an answer, and it will probably be closed later when it gets bumped looking for an answer.